# Convert from nullable object into nonnull (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, nullable, xcode6.3

I've been using the new [nullability](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) stuff in Xcode 6.3

However, I'm running into an issue like this

```
[Object doSomethingWithNonNullParam:otherObject.nullableProperty];
```

Whats the best way to solve this If I'm confident `otherObject.nullableProperty` is not `nil`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think a cast here is appropriate?

`[Object doSomethingWithNonNullParam:(OtherObject *_Nonnull) otherObject.nullableProperty];`